# isset( $_SESSION[] ) and MySQL request

Tags: php, mysql, session, session-variables, session-state

I want to create session while there is not defined session. When I update my sites table on MYSQL while I have a defined session I don't want to see fresh data. Also I don't want to request to DB. But below code brings to me fresh data from DB. site_title is `<title>$SITE_TITLE</title>`

```
if ( isset($_SESSION["SESSION_AVAIABLE"]) == FALSE ) {
$_SESSION["SESSION_AVAIABLE"] =TRUE;

//fetch 
$site_info = $central_db->query("SELECT * FROM sites WHERE site_id = 100 ");
$site_info->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$site_data = $site_info->fetch();

//create sessions
$_SESSION["site_title"] = $site_data["site_title"];
$SITE_TITLE = $_SESSION["site_title"];

$_SESSION["site_description"] = $site_data["site_description"];
$SITE_DESC = $_SESSION["site_description"];

var_dump(isset($_SESSION["SESSION_AVAIABLE"]));
}

else {
 echo "sessions are avaiable";
 }
```

Comment: `session_start();` at the top of the script?

Comment: yes I have added session_start()